# Orthogonal complement in a finite field ${\mathbb Z}^{n}_{q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> When $V=\mathbb{Z}^n_q$ is a vector space, where $\mathbb Z_q$ is the set of integers modulo prime $q>2$, are the following statements true?
>
> 1. If $U ⊂ V$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace, then
>      $$
>    U^⊥= \{ x∈V∣x^Tu=0 \ \mathrm {for\ all}\ u∈U \}
>    $$
>      is of dimension $n-k$.
> 2. (If statement 1 is true) $U^⊥$ can be written by $n-k$ orthogonal vectors.

For an example of statement 1, if $V=\mathbb{Z}^3_3$, and $U=\{ a_1(1,2,1)^T+a_2(0,1,1)^T\ |\ \forall a_1,a_2\in\mathbb Z_3\} $  then $U^⊥$ can be expressed with basis $(1,2,1)^T$.

I'm not familiar with using linear algebra in finite fields, so I don't know how I should handle "orthogonal" vectors. I wrote down some examples and am pretty sure that statement 1 holds in finite fields, as it does in real case, but I'm not so certain of statement 2. Furthermore, I don't have a clue on how to prove these statements.

I'm not used to using English, so if there's anything wrong with my explanation, don't hesitate to ask. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Correct. 1 is true, 2 is false, as user33433 describes in their answer. As you are using the coding theory tag I can't resist to remark that in coding theory the so called self-dual codes are a well studied object. These are subspaces with the property $U=U^\perp$. For example the famous binary extended Golay code $G$ is a 12-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{Z}_2^{24}$ such that $G=G^\perp$.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. And I apologize for misleading you all by using the term "Orthonormal" in statement 2, where I should of used the term "Orthogonal". It was my first time using these terms so got them mixed up. Mike & J Swanson, thank you for the neat proof for statement 1!! It'll be great if you could rethink statement 2 again.(Since now I don't think that the statement is that obvious...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You probably want to apply rank-nullity, so find a linear transformation which expresses $U^\perp$ as an image or kernel. For instance, consider the linear transformations $T_u \colon V \to \mathbb{Z}_q$ given by $x \mapsto x^T u$. Then $U^\perp = \cap_{u \in U} \ker T_u$. Fix a basis $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ of $U$; it's clear $U^\perp = \cap_{u_i} \ker T_{u_i}$. Glue the transformations together by considering $T \colon V \to \mathbb{Z}_q^k$ given by $x \mapsto (x^T u_i)_{i=1}^k$. Hence $U^\perp = \ker T$, so $\dim U^\perp = n - \dim {\rm im}(T)$. So, we just need to show $\dim {\rm im}(T) = k$. For that, notice that $T$ is given by right-multiplying $x^T$ by the matrix $(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ ($u_i$ being column vectors here). By definition, this has column-span of dimension $k$, so it has row-span of dimension $k$, so $\dim {\rm im}(T) = k$. (For reference on this part, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Proofs_that_column_rank_.3D_row_rank).)
2. Since it's possible for $u^T u = 0$ for $u \neq 0$, one can't interpret $u^T u$ as (square) "length" and divide by it. I can't think of anything else "orthonormal" would refer to. Edit: Ah, you actually mean "orthogonal", in the sense that you want a basis $\{u_i\}$ for $U^\perp$ where $u_i^T u_j = 0$ for all $i \neq j$. It's a little hard to find counterexamples, since the Gram-Schmidt process actually works with the usual inner product replaced by $u^T v$, at least whenever you don't divide by $0$, i.e. whenever none of your intermediate vectors satisfies $u^T u = 0$. A problem with Mike's subspace is that it's a subset of $Z = \{u \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n : u^T u = 0\}$. Interestingly, it seems $Z$ is itself a vector subspace if and only if $q=2$ (more generally, in characteristic $2$). Maybe this will help guide the construction of a counterexample/a proof that no counterexamples exist for $q>2$?

Comment: @ruparunpa If by "$u$ and $v$ are orthogonal" you mean $u^T v = 0$, Mike's provided you a counterexample to the revised version of (2) at the top of his post.

Comment: Ahh I see!! I hate to keep on adding to my question, but do you think statement 2 will suffice even if q is a prime larger than 2? Because I've been thinking of this problem with q=3 for a while, but still haven't managed to find a counterexample. And the application I have in mind requires q to be a very large prime, so it would be helpful if a counterexample was given for any q except 2.

Comment: @ruparunpa I've edited my answer. If you find a complete answer, please mention it here.

Answer (score 6):

(2) is  false. For example, if $U$ is the 1D subspace $\{(0,0,0), (1,1,1)\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$, then $U^\bot$ is the 2D subspace $\{(0,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)\}$ which has no orthogonal basis.

(1) is true. Here's a sketch without all the details.

> **Claim 1:** Let $X$ be a vector space over a field $F$. Suppose $x_1,\ldots,x_k \in X$ are vectors, $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_k \in X^*$ are functionals, and that $\varphi_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$, the Kronecker delta. Then, $x \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^k \varphi_i(x) x_i$ is a rank-$k$ projection with range $\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ and kernel $\bigcap_{i=1}^k \ker(\varphi_i)$. In particular (e.g. by rank-nullity), $\dim(X) = k + \dim \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^k \ker(\varphi_i) \right)$.
>
> **Claim 2:** Let $X$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let $\varphi_1,\ldots, \varphi_k \in X^*$ be functionals. Then, $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_k$ are linearly independent in $X^*$ if and only if  there exist $x_1,\ldots,x_k \in X$ such that $\varphi_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

Claim 1 is quite direct. One of the implications of Claim 2 is easy, and the other implication comes from a Gramm-Schmidt type construction using Claim 1.

Now, in your situation, the standard inner-product on $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ can be thought of as a choice of isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_q^n \cong (\mathbb{Z}_q^n)^*$ so that $U$ can be thought of as a subpace of $(\mathbb{Z}_q^n)^*$. Choose a basis $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ for $U$, note $U^\bot = \bigcap_{i=1}^k \ker(\varphi_i)$ in this instance, and apply the equality from Claim 1.

Comment: I forgot to read your counterexample for statement 2. And you are completely right! I totally forgot to take in account of q=2. But like I wrote to J Swanson, and I apologize to you in advance for having to keep adding to my question, I was considering q to be a prime bigger than 2. I've been working on the case when q=3, and so far I haven't found any counterexample and statement 2 seems to be quite legitimate.

Comment: @ruparunpa: No problem, it's a great question! By the way, for subspaces $U \subset \mathbb{Z}_q^n$, you get the expected relation $(U^\bot)^\bot = U$ (clearly $U \subset (U^\bot)^\bot$ and the dimensions match  by your question 1). As a consequence, every subspace $U \subset \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ is of the form $V^\bot$ for $V = U^\bot$. So, your question 2 is really the same as "does every subspace of $\mathbb{Z}^n_q$ have an orthonormal basis?"

Answer (score -2):

You haven't said what your definition of $U^\perp$ is, so it's rather hard to check whether it's equal to something.  You also don't say what goal or application you have in mind, so it's also hard to suggest how to get there.

But orthogonality over finite fields is a very strange concept, and certainly does not perfectly translate from the real case.  For example, suppose that $n=q$, and $U=\langle u \rangle$, where $u=(1,1,\ldots,1)$.  Then $u^T u = 1+1+\ldots+1 = q = 0$, so $u\in U^\perp$ if we use the above definition!

Also, you should keep in mind that, just like over $\mathbb{Q}$, you might have to extend the field to scale a basis to be orthonormal.  For instance, take $(1,1)$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$.  Then the normalized vector is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1,1)$.  But $2$ isn't a square in $\mathbb{F}_3$!  We need to look in $\mathbb{F}_9^2$, the vector space over the field with 9 elements, to find the normalized vector.

With these caveats, much of the same theory works.  For example, it seems to be true that $\dim{U} + \dim{U^\perp} = \dim V$, if we use your Statement #1 as a definition.  But it's no longer true that $V=U+U^\perp$, since we may have $U\cap U^\perp \neq 0$.

As a general rule, things that you can prove using the basic algebra of matrices and determinants will still be true, while anything requiring the inner product might fail if it uses properties of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm sorry for causing you trouble. I misused the term orthonormal. What I meant in statement 2 was "orthogonal". To answer your question, $U^⊥$ is supposed to be the orthogonal complement of *U*. And I was hoping on applying this knowledge to improve the safety of an encryption called IPE, which uses the quality of inner products in integers modulo prime q.

Comment: @ruparunpa But what is "orthogonal"?  Saying that $U^\perp$ is supposed to be the orthogonal complement is like saying it's supposed to be "U perp"; it's just terminology.  It seems like there is no natural complementation of subspaces over a finite field.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Isn't $U^⊥=\{x∈V∣x^Tu=0 \ for \ all \ u∈U\}$ a definition of $U^⊥$?? And I do fell weird using the term "orthogonal", since $U^⊥⊕U=V$ does not satisfy, but I couldn't think of better term to use than "Orthogonal".

Comment: What does it mean to normalize a vector in positive characteristic? There is no norm here to work with.

Comment: @seaturtles There is still something like a norm, namely $\lVert x \rVert := \langle x,x\rangle$.  As long as $\lVert x \rVert$ isn't zero, it's meaningful to talk about $x/\sqrt{\lVert x \rVert}$.