# Number of vectors orthogonal to a fixed vector

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

I have a $k$-sized vector $(x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_k)$ where each $x_i$  has been drawn randomly from $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

- What is the average number of vectors ($\in \mathbb{Z}^k_n$) orthogonal to it?
- If I have such a concrete vector, with $k=4$ and $n=5$, for instance $(2,0,4,1)$, How can I compute the number of orthogonal vectors to it?

Thank you.

Comment: @copper.hat Each $x_i$ is picked (uniformly) at random in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: I realised that the $n$ was a subscript after my comment, Excuse the noise.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the integers modulo $n$?

Comment: @Wouter Yes, it's $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. I've updated my post.

Comment: Maybe related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621117/orthogonal-complement-in-a-finite-field-mathbb-zn-q

Comment: Just curious, do you mean orthogonal in the $\mathbb{R}$ sense or in a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ sense?